# Association name in Visio 2010 UML Diagram

Tags: uml, visio

I have an UML Diagram with Visio 2010, and the association name is not showing above the line in the diagram.

I double-clicked the association, wrote something in the Name field, clicked ok but the name is not showing up.

Does somebody have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Visio does not display association names.

You have to check "Name" in the section "General options" in the "UML Shape Display Options" panel that you get with the diagram element's context menu (so pick your association and rightclick).